# Develop AB Testing on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

What are the methodologies applied on Xamarin to implement A/B test? 
Is there any framework or pattern currently compatible and applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Clutch.io is an option. It was made OSS recently so you can get up and running with it for free. There is some setup though as you have to deploy the server piece to you own servers.

[Clutch.io on Github](https://github.com/clutchio)

Comment: Thanks @Blounty but i'd like to find something in C#. But that is an option ;)

Comment: I searched for quite some time and did not find anything written in c# specifically for mobile a/b testing. Maybe an opportunity there. :)

Comment: I have actually started writing something if it is of any interest?

Comment: Did you ever find an A/B testing solution for Xamarin?